# git commit count for each branch in date range

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am  in a repository where there are many branches. I want to get commit count happening on each branch in a specific date range like in Month of September or October 2017 how many commits happened on that specific branch.

I used something like this :

```
git log --pretty=format:"%ad - %an: %s" --after="2017-12-01" --until="2017-12-31" | wc -l
```

but this show for master. I cannot checkout the branches as i have cloned  bare repository only. 
The primary purpose is to get a reporting tool only.

Can somebody help me in getting the solution. Thank You.

Comment: the problem is i am using bitbucket and there is no apis as such. So i am trying git command variations to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name any branch:

```
git log --oneline --after="2017-12-01" --before="2017-12-31" branch | wc -l
```

But I wonder what will you do with commits that belong to many branches?

Comment: Thank You it works. Just need count to create a report.